# how do i split comma separated string in JS excluding json data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a string as

```
ABC, CDE, [{"ab":"1","cv":"23"},{"ab":"1","cv":"2%3A1639251967619%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D"}]
```

I want to split to get array of length 3 two strings and 3rd string with json array as string

```
ABC
CDE
[{"ab":"1","cv":"23"},{"ab":"1","cv":"2%3A1639251967619%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D"}]
```

using JS

Comment: Based on this string, did you try to split on ", " so a comma and a space? I hope, the real string has the same format

Comment: @AxisStarstreamer i did comma space but my problem was even if the string goes like this
ABC,CDE,[{"ab":"1","cv":"23"},{"ab":"1","cv":"2%3A1639251967619%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D"}]

Comment: @AxisStarstreamer Actual scenario is i have string with
username, password, cookiedata 
i wanted to separate this in to 3
username
password
cookiedata

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `split` method like this:

```js
const str = 'ABC,CDE,[{"ab":"1","cv":"23"},{"ab":"1","cv":"2%3A1639251967619%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D"}]';
let value = str.replace(/\w,/g, (match) => match[0] + '#').split('#');
// if you want to convert 3rd item to a valid JS object you can parse it, else you can miss next line:
value[2] = JSON.parse(value[2]);
console.log(value)
```

Comment: hey i m sorry i wrote the example like that but how to do it if string is
const str = 'ABC,CDE,[{"ab":"1","cv":"23"},{"ab":"1","cv":"2%3A1639251967619%2C%22v%22%3A1%7D"}]';
there no space after the comma

Comment: I edited my response, could you please check it out.